# An $R_0$ space can't have Sierpinski space as its subspace. Proof Verification.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm not sure if my proof is right and if it is not could you please point me to the mistake.

**Proof by contradiction.**

Defining Sierpinski Space as: $\underline S = (\{0,1\}, \{\{0, 1\}, \{1\}, \emptyset\})$

Since $\underline S$ is a subspace of some space $\underline Y$, which is $R_0$, then such an initial map exists:

$m: \underline S \rightarrow \underline Y$

We denote:

$m(0) = y_0, m(1) = y_1$

Due to Y being $R_0$ and $m$ being continuous, we have:

$0 \in cl_S(\{1\}) \Rightarrow y_0 \in cl_Y(\{y_1\}) \Rightarrow y_1 \in cl_Y(\{y_0\})$

Since $\underline S$ is an initial topology and $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $\underline S$, then:

$\exists B \subset Y, B \ \text - closed: m^{-1}[B] = \{ 0 \}, \ \text{also note that} \ y_0 \in B$

Then:

$cl_Y\{y_0\} \subset B$

And so:

$y_1 \in cl_Y\{y_0\} \subset B$, so $y_1 \in B$

But then:

$1 = m^{-1}(y_1) \in m^{-1}[B] = \{0\}$

From the last follows that $1 \in \{0\}$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, no such initial map $m$ can exist, so $\underline S$ is not a subspace of $\underline Y$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, but it’s far more complicated than necessary. Suppose that $\langle Y,\tau\rangle$ is $R_0$ and has a subspace homeomorphic to the Sierpiński space; then there are distinct points $y_0,y_1\in Y$ such that

$$U\cap\{y_0,y_1\}\in\big\{\varnothing,\{y_1\},\{y_0,y_1\}\big\}$$

for each $U\in\tau$, and there is at least one $U_1\in\tau$ such that $U_1\cap\{y_0,y_1\}=\{y_1\}$. $Y$ is $R_0$, and $U_1$ is an open nbhd of $y_1$ that is not an open nbhd of $y_0$, so $y_0$ and $y_1$ are separated in $Y$, i.e., each has an open nbhd that does not contain the other. But then there is a $U_0\in\tau$ such that $U_0\cap\{y_0,y_1\}=\{y_0\}$, which is impossible. Thus, $Y$ has no such subspace.